# Add an element in each value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that gives the date (its type is str) and another column that gives a first name, I would like all the names that are in 2020 have "_2020" at the end of their first name, and same thing for 2021, and its pandas DataFrame.

As I have thousands of rows, I need a loop that automates the task.

it would be like going from this:

| Time | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-26 | John |
| 2020-05-06 | Jack |
| 2021-03-06 | Steve |

To That:

| Time | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-26 | John_2020 |
| 2020-05-06 | Jack_2020 |
| 2021-03-06 | Steve_2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
#ensure that Time column is of dtype datetime[ns]
df['Name']=df['Name']+'_'+df['Time'].dt.year.astype(str)
#finally assign columns
```

output of df:

```
    Time        Name
0   2020-12-26  John_2020
1   2020-05-06  Jack_2020
2   2021-03-06  Steve_2021
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider your DataFrame is named `df`.

This should do the trick:

```py
df['Name'] = df[['Time', 'Name']].apply(lambda t: f'{t[1]}_{t[0].split("-")[0]}', axis=1)
```

With plain words, what this does is:

- It applies a lambda function on each `(Time, Name)` couple.
- This lambda function returns the `Name`, an underscore and the `yyyy` of the date.
- Writes those values over what was previously the `Name` column of your DataFrame.

It is not the smartest way and you must ensure every date has the same format `yyyy-mm-dd`, but it works fine.
Also make sure there are no `NaN` values.

**Edit**: Another version inspired by another response of this thread is the following:

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'] + '_' + df['Time'].apply(lambda time: time.split('-')[0])
```

It is perhaps a bit less efficient but it is more understandable. It suffers the same constraints as the method I previously suggested.